# WPF browser based application create problems on different browsers

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I want to know is there any way out to run WPF-browser based application on different browsers other then I.E and firefox. I figure out that WPF successfully run on IE and firefox but create lot if issues on rest of the browsers. one thing pop in my mind to create dll but dont know the process or one way through iframe. please need help

Comment: WPF is a Windows desktop application technology. It's not intended to be used to create web applications. If you need a web application you need to use HTML and javascript (ASP.Net or other web framework)

Comment: I'm going to assume by "WPF-browser based" you mean Silverlight. If the browser demographic covered by Silverlight is too small to be acceptable you need to choose a different technology. A list of supported Silverlight OS/Browser combinations can be found on the "System Requirements" tab here: http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/Get-Started/Install/Default.aspx